# What is the etymology of shamisen (三味線)?

Tags: kanji, etymology, ateji

The instrument clearly has 3 (三) strings (線), but where does 味 exactly fit in?

Comment: a quick look on [isho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%91%B3-1) says it's a counter for "food, drink, medicine, etc.​"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The instrument originated in China as the [三弦]{sānxián}, and it came to Japan via Okinawa.  The Okinawan instrument's soundbox is covered with a snakeskin.  The older Japanese name for it was 蛇皮【じゃび】線【せん】, literally "snakeskin strings".  This instrument was introduced to the Osaka area from Okinawa during the 永禄【えいろく】 era (1558-1570).  Over time, the *jabi* portion on the front shifted pronunciation to *shami*: the "j" became unvoiced "sh", and the "b" lost its plosive-ness to become nasal "m".

The 三味 spelling for the *shami* portion is an example of *ateji*, with some meaning overtones of *jukujikun* in the use of 三 to refer to the three strings, and (as far as I can tell) pure phonetics for the 味.

See also [the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E5%91%B3%E7%B7%9A#Japanese) (full disclosure: I edited that), and the monlingual Japanese sources at [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B8%89%E5%91%B3%E7%B7%9A-76278) and [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%89%E5%91%B3%E7%B7%9A).

Answer (score -5):

I'm not sure about this one as i am not a specialist in the question. But in my opinion it may be some kind of a meaning extension.

As 味 also means "a flavour", it might be that 三味線 is "three [good] flavour strings". And the meaning of a "[good] flavour" is just somehow extended to sounds made by the instrument. So it transforms in something like "three [good] sounding strings".

Not sure,though.